# Make "sudo apt-get update" output only what it is doing on one line

Tags: apt, bash

I want `sudo apt-get update` to report about what it is doing on single line rather than filling the terminal window with its output. I don't want to hide possible error messages, though.

I mean something like this, but writing the last line that changes and is not visible after that in the output of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
sudo apt-get update | xargs -I{} printf '%-*s\r' $(tput cols) "{}"
printf '\n
```

Also would be nice, if it could write given number of lines, and scrolling those lines without hiding the text preceding its output in terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

This will be difficult to do without writing a proper application that uses ncurses or similar to control the terminal. With bash, you can get some of this effect with the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash
height=${1:-5}

# Buffer up to the height
do_height()
{
    for ((i = 0; i < height; i++))
    do
        "$@"
    done
}

do_height printf "%-${cols}s\n" ""

# Get dimensions of terminal
cols=$(tput cols)
lines=$(tput lines)

sudo apt-get update |&
    while IFS= read -r line
    do 
        sleep 0.01
        if [[ $line =~ ^(Hit|Get|Fetch|Read) ]]
        then
            out=("$line" "${out[@]:0:4}")
        else
            out=("" "${out[@]:0:4}")
            tput cup $((lines - height - 1)) 0
            printf "%-${cols}s\n" "$line"
            do_height printf "%-${cols}s\n" ""
        fi
        tput cup $((lines - height - 1)) 0
        for ((i = height - 1; i >= 0; i--))
        do
            printf "%-${cols}s\n" "${out[i]}"
        done
    done
```

Run as `foo.sh N` where N is the number of lines you want to keep. Note that:

- this assumes you're at the bottom of the terminal.
- errors will always be printed N lines above the last line.
- `apt-get` provides more transient output when it's printing to a terminal, so the output here will seem jerky as intermediate lines are not available.

So the final output will  look like:

[image]

Comment: Even this does not print the line telling the status i.e. percentage following some other text that you see on bottom when running `sudo apt-get update`. I think that line would be valuable to know, if progress slows down for some reason.

Comment: @jarno try running `apt-get update | cat`

Comment: That does not help.

Comment: @jarno no, it doesn't. But if you did try it, you'll see that apt-get doesn't output that information when it's not printing to a tty. So a command which tries to process apt-get's output will never get that information. So either you write a new tool to replace apt-get, or live with missing progress information. I have already noted this in the answer.